# Buck / step down voltage in limited space

Tags: voltage-regulator, buck, switching-regulator, step-down, power-dissipation

I am designing a small PCB.  The supply voltage is 12V, but I also need 5V with supply of maximum 250mA.

The most obvious solution is to use voltage regulator - there are plenty of them and some like MCP1702/1703 support larger currents.  The problem is of course the power dissipation, which is (12V-5V)*0.25A = **1.75W**.

SMD packages have very high thermal resistance - looking MCP1702/1703 manual they are 110K/W for SOT89 and even 336K/W for SOT23A.  Taking maximum temperature of 125C and room temperature of 25C, this is **0.9W** of **heat dissipation** at most for SOT89.  I find this relatively small, as SOT89 even has a thermal pad.

So is there any solution, like putting a large chunk of copper on PCB or perhaps even glue a piece of aluminium to SOT89 casing?

Alternatively, I could use switching regulator.  However those usually require several additional elements - for example, TPS54202H requires six, four more than standard voltage regulator.

Is there any workaround for this problem - get 5V 250mA but without using a lot of space?  What is your experience?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Edit: **Summary: If I use voltage regulator, only two additional elements are necessary and only around 40mm2 are used, but there is too much heat dissipation.  If I use switching regulator, there is very little heat dissipation, but a lot of space is used as six additional elements are necessary.  I hope to use less than 50mm2 and elements that could be hand soldered.**

Comment: The long comment chain has exceeded what is reasonable for comments. Therefore it has been moved to chat and should be continued there (link below). --- As this bulk moving of comments to chat can only be done once per question, any further comments posted here to discuss / clarify the question, might be deleted without notice. **Keep it in chat, please!** When someone has got enough information from the chat to post an answer, then please do that as usual. Thanks.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127654/discussion-on-question-by-pygmalion-buck-step-down-voltage-in-limited-space).

Answer (score 4):

Monolithic Power Systems has an entire line of DC-DC converters with an integrated regulator+inductor, some with very small footprints (as small as 3x3mm). They’ve been my go-to for a while. TI also has a line of integrated-inductor converters. There are others but these would be my top two. They’re very easy to use, needing just the bypass caps and voltage divider to set the output voltage.

A lower-cost approach could use an SOT-23 switcher IC from companies like Diodes Inc, Richtek, etc. At the power rating you’re talking about you can use a low-profile 2x2 or 2x2.5mm inductor.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  It seems that integrated-inductors are difficult to find (I was looking at Mouser and Monolithic Power Systems for 5V and could not find any). So I guess the low cost approach is what I need.  By the way, the inductor from the Marcus Müller's solution (10uH and 200mOhm) is actually pretty big (3.5mm x 2.8), plus a voltage divider is required, which unfortunately makes everything relatively large (for my application).

Comment: @Pygmalion exactly what is your application?

Comment: @BruceAbbott I am making a DCC decoder - this is a device that is put into model locomotives - which means that space is really tight.  I am optimizing PCBs for hours just to save a fraction of millimeter.

Comment: The Diodes Inc AP3211 can work with a 4.7 uH inductor in 2520 size. 4.5 ~ 17V input. https://www.diodes.com/part/view/AP3211#tab-details

Comment: And a suitable inductor: https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Taiyo-Yuden/MAMK2520T4R7M

Comment: @Pygmalion that's what I suspected (I am currently designing a DCC decoder for very small N scale locomotives, so I understand your concerns).

Comment: Unfortunately, AP3211 requires additional bootstrap capacitor, so we are essentially back to square one.

Comment: @BruceAbbott I am trying to make NmraDcc.h compatible decoder based on Geoff Bunza's work, using microchip directly and using voltage divider instead of optocoupler.  I wonder if I can include sound with DFPlayer in which case I need 5V line with larger currents.  If you are moving in the same direction, maybe we could share experiences.

Answer (score 3):

A buck converter is the right choice here; don't know where the impression these would need a lot of space; there's many that need exactly three external components (an inductor and a capacitor on the output, one on the input for decoupling), exactly one more than your LDO (which you'd still want to equip with an input decoupling capacitor). If the regulator has adjustable output voltage, you'd also need two resistors as voltage dividers, true.

I personally wouldn't force myself to design that tightly, but I'd think that with a SOT23-5 Buck IC, 0603 decoupling on the input, 0805 on the output, and 0402 or 0201 resistors, you'd end up with less than 10 mm × 7 mm of board space.

Example design (four clicks, three entered numbers): https://webench.ti.com/appinfo/webench/scripts/SDP.cgi?ID=3803E93DAF24BA56

Count the external components: it's 5, even if you include both the Cinx and Cin, one of which you might not even need if your board already has that.

[image: schematic.]

This will fit, without any problem within the 50 mm² you have, with 0805 passives.

Quick calculation, erring on the side of "larger than needed"

- Buck converter IC (the example uses one in a SOT23-5 package): 3×2mm for a hand-soldering footprint = 6 mm²
- three capacitors and two resistors in 0805 with a hand-soldering footprint: 4mm long, 1.25 mm wide = 5 mm² each (that is **really** super relaxed to solder), so 25 mm² in total
- 10 µH inductor, for ca 1 A rated: these [exist in 2012](https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Taiyo-Yuden/LBC3225T100KR?qs=PzICbMaShUfZVMW%252BOICEZw%3D%3D) packages, so hand-solderable footprint would be around 5 mm × 2.5 mm, 7.5 mm²

Total 38.5mm².

Comment: The long comment chain has exceeded what is reasonable for comments. Therefore it has been moved to chat and should be continued there (link below). --- As this bulk moving of comments to chat can only be done once per answer, any further comments posted here to discuss the answer, might be deleted without notice. **Keep it in chat, please!** Thanks.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127653/discussion-on-answer-by-marcus-muller-buck-step-down-voltage-in-limited-space).